# how to show default select option value through ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two select box and second select box values depend upon first box value.

Its ajax call when selected any value in first select box and second box updated automatically with value.

I want to first vale in the select box is "Select" after ajax call.

Please help.

```
success: function(data)
{
    var optionHtml="";
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data, function(index,object){

        optionHtml = optionHtml  +
                         "<option value= '"+object.rule_name+"' > "  
                          +object.rule_name+"</option>";

    });
    $('#rankTypeSel').html(optionHtml);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Append select option first in select box like below

```
success: function(data)
        {
            var optionHtml="";
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(data, function(index,object){

                optionHtml = optionHtml  +
                                 "<option value= '"+object.rule_name+"' > "  
                                  +object.rule_name+"</option>";

            });

            var optionWithSelect = "<option value= '-1' > Selelct </option>"+optionHtml;
            $('#rankTypeSel').html(optionWithSelect );


        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $("<option>SELECT</option>", { value: '', selected: true }).prependTo("#rankTypeSel");​​​​​​​​​​​
```